# Wordpress вывести все значения произвольных полей без повторения

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть произвольный тип записей, записи этого типа имеют два произвольных поля, поле1 имеет одно из двух значений, поле2 - любое. Как мне получить все значения этих полей со всех постов блога? В идеале сгруппировать их по полю 1, либо получить сначала те, что имеют первое значение поля1, затем те, что со вторым.

Я нашел примерно то, что нужно вот здесь https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/getting-all-values-for-a-custom-field-key-cross-post но нужно избежать повторения значений, иначе смысл теряется.

Суть в том, что эти значения мне нужно сформировать в dropdown, чтобы использовать при поиске.

Comment: ну а почему массив meta_values не пропустить через array_unique() ?

Comment: @KAGGDesign возможно, для вас это слишком просто,но не могли бы вы, в таком случае, просто оформить ваше решение ответом?

Comment: Ответ сделал, но из вопроса не вполне понятно, вам один dropdown нужен или два?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте array_unique() в один из вариантов ответа на указанный вами вопрос:

```
<?php

function get_meta_values( $meta_key, $post_type = 'post' ) {

    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => $post_type,
            'meta_key'       => $meta_key,
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        )
    );

    $meta_values = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $meta_values[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true );
    }

    return array_unique( $meta_values );

}

$meta_values1 = get_meta_values( 'key1', 'post' );
$meta_values2 = get_meta_values( 'key2', 'post' );
```

Так вы получите два массива с уникальными значениями ключей `key1` и `key2`, которые можете использовать в двух dropdown списках.

Comment: Благодарю, сработало, как надо